# How to Call Function of one class on the object of another class?

Tags: c++, oop, class, function, function-call

How can I call one method in one class over using another class ?

I have ;

```
class A { 
 public :
  foo ( ) ;
};

class B {
 public :
  bar ( ) ;
};
```

in main :

```
A data ;          // I am creating instance of class A 

data . bar ( ) ;  //  but, I am calling a method of another class

                  // how can I do that ?
```

Note : I could not find a appropriate title. If you have one, feel free to share or edit

Comment: A quick reference to deriving classes might be helpful. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class

Answer (score 1):

Unless the two classes are related(through inheritance) You cannot do that.

A member functions performs some action on the instance of the class to which it belongs.
You created an object of class `A` so you can only call member functions of `A` through it.

Grinding an Apple and hoping to get a mango shake, won't really happen right.

Answer (score 1):

Use public inheritance:

```
class B {
 public:
  void bar();
};

class A : public B
{ };

int main() {
 A a;
 a.bar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want use .bar() on A object A must inherit by B.

Comment: ? Answer : "class B : class A"

Comment: that's private inheritance. It may not achieve what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want `data.bar()` to do.

`bar()` as no access to A's data, so `bar()` cannot have anything to do with the variable `data`. So, I would argue, that `data.bar()` is unnecessary, you are aiming for just `bar()`.
Presumably, if `bar()` is just a function, you can declare it `static` and call `B.data()`

The other option is that you wanted inheritance which some other people have already written about. Be careful with inheritance, and make sure you inherit A from B only if you there is a is-a relationship, and it satisfies the [Liskov Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). Don't inherit from B just because you have to call `bar()`.

If you want to use B, you can have a instance of B inside A. Read about [prefering composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

As everyone said in their answers.
Its a bad idea and not possible.

You can only use tricks that no one really knows how its gonna behave.

You can get the pointer of an object A and cast it to be poiter of B.

Again the only use of that is to show other what not to do.

```
A a;
B* b = (B*)&a;
b->bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read 1 or 2 c plus plus book(s) and get a fair idea what classes are about and what purpose they are meant to serve.

Some suggestions: The c++ programing by Bjarne Stroustrup or Thinking in c++ by Bruce Eckel or search over net for tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function pointer. The only way to make it not static is to use templates.

```
class A
{ 
  public:
  void setBar(void (*B::func)(void)) { bar = func; };
  void callBar() { bar(); };

  private:
  void(*B::bar)(void);
};

class B
{
  public:
  static void bar() { printf("you called bar!"); };
};

int main() {
  A a;
  a.setBar(B::bar);
  a.callBar();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare class `B` as a `friend` of class `A`.

I believe the syntax for it is:

```
class A {
    public:
        foo();
    friend class B;
};
class B {
    public:
        bar();
};
```

But with this, I believe you can only use functions/variables from `A` inside `B` functions.
Inheritance will probably be your better approach to it.

Answer (score -1):

Although this question is strange !, but here are some solutions
Using inheritance

```
class A: public B
```

Type cast

```
A data;
((B*)&data)->bar();
```

Or reinterpret cast

```
B* b = reinterpret_cast <B*> (&data);
b->bar();
```

If bar() use any member variables of B, then the result is not predictable.

Comment: The cast versions both cause undefined behaviour

Comment: Both cast versions are actually equivalent. If bar() doesn't make use of any non-static member variable form B, it can be specified as a  static member function without any error or effect.

Comment: If bar() doesn't make use of any non-static member variable form B, it acts like a static function. It can be specified as a  static member function without any error or side effects. Then any valid pointer of the type B* can be used to invoke bar() without error. Try it!.